# setListAdapter is undefined for type create

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to read the name of contacts on my phone but when it comes to the `setListAdapter()` I keep getting the error mentioned above.

When I `extends ListActivity` instead of `Activity` there are no errors but the applicaton force closes.

Also I tried to extend `Activity` and `ListActivity` by creating another class inside of Create that extended `listActivity` but nothing was displayed. Im displaying on `create.xml` list view. This `create.java` occurs when the user clicks on create button that was made in my `main.xml` file

**Create.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class Create extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create);

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.create);


    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        list.add(name);
    }

    setListAdapter(list);
    }
}
```

**This is create.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/create_button_title"
    android:textSize="24.5sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dip"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dip">

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/contacts_label"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/choose_contacts"
       android:hint="@string/choose_contacts" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/choose_contacts"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:text="@string/contacts_button"
       />

   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/contacts_list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="44dip"
       ></ListView>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if you are using `setListAdapter()` your activity must `extends ListActivity`

Comment: @Rustam how in the world did your edit make this post better?

Comment: @codeMagic last `}` was not in your code section.

Comment: @Rustam But you removed all of my formatting of the actual question which made it more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it when `extends Activity` you need to get a reference to your `ListView` in `onCreate()`

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);`
```

then use the method `setAdapter()` on it

```
lv.setAdapter(list);
```

`setListAdapter()` and `getListView()` are convenience methods when extending `ListActivity` and won't work when extending any other class.

As far as why it wasn't working when you had `extends ListActivity`, it's hard to say without seeing the stacktrace from the crash.

[If you look at the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) the `layout should be

> resource  The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.

it should contain **only** a `TextView`. If you want the other `View`s then you should create a custom `Adapter` and override `getView()`. This is all explained in the docs at the very top.

You can find plenty of tutorials/examples on how to do this by searching The Google for something like "Custom adapter ListView Android".

Comment: There are no errors now but I still have the same problem when I press the create button the application closes and I get the message process... com.contacts has crashed, I added the listview lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.contacts)list) and lv.setAdapter(list) and took out the setListAdapter(list)

Comment: If it crashes, there is a crash log

Comment: it says for ArrayAdapter you must supply a resource id for a textview